# Apple standard settings bar icon on the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, icons, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I need to put settings icon on the right of my Navigation Bar and would like to use Apple's own settings icon from General in Settings app (the gear icon). Is this allowed and if these icons are accessible, how can I get them? So far I could only reach a subset of Apple's icons in xcode like Action, Add, Bookmarks ... Undo from UIBarButtonSystemItem, but there is no symbol resembling settings.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wantapplestdhere.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(selectorMethod:)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for whether or not usage of the icons is allowed. However, they are accessible. Just download [0xced's iOS-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor) and run it on the simulator. It will give you a dump of every image bundled into the iOS simulator that you run it on, which I believe is all of them.